# Does installing an R package with Rcpp require Rtools (Windows)

Tags: r, rcpp, cran

I am making an R package with Rcpp. It works fine on my machine which has Rtools installed. But recently, I tried to install my package locally on a different machine (Windows) and got a compiling error. The reason was that on that machine there was no g++ compiler (for Windows, g++ is provided with Rtools). After installing Rtools, it worked just fine.

So the question is, if I upload it to CRAN, does it still requires users to install Rtools by hand? Or does the function `install.package()` detect and install Rtools for them?

Also, if you guys know some packages written with Rcpp, please let me know. I'd like to take a look how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So the question is, if I upload it to CRAN, does it still requires users to install Rtools by hand?

No.

> Or does the function `install.package()` detect and install Rtools for them?

No.

What happens is that CRAN builds pre-compiled binary files that can be installed by Windows and MacOS users without the need for compilers and related tools.

> Also, if you guys know some packages written with Rcpp, please let me know. I'd like to take a look how it works.

```
rr <- devtools::revdep("Rcpp")
length(rr) ## 907
```

or see the [Rcpp page on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rcpp).

Comment: Good answer. They is the difference between *source* and *binary* installations from a repository, and for the latter you do *not* need Rtools as pointed out here.  Also FWIW when I count Rcpp's reverse-depends (with some filtering against false positives) I currently get 899, not 907.

Comment: I uploaded to CRAN. But it shows Windows binaries not available! And when I install it via install.package(), it only downloads the source package then complies locally. Did I mess up something?

Comment: It usually takes a few days for Windows binaries to be built and propagate to the mirrors.

Answer (score 4):

*Users*, e.g. people who download it via `install.package()`, are actually downloading a "compiled" version of the packaged called a binary that is maintained by CRAN. They will only ever need a copy of R.

On the other hand, *Developers*, e.g. people who are creating it, require development tools that are system specific. For those on **the Windows platform**, they must have a local install of [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) on their machine. For *developers* on **macOS**, they must have their own copies of [gfortran binaries and xcode developer line tools](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/install-rtools-for-rcpp/).

Lastly, there are many such Rcpp packages available to look to for inspiration...

- See the [Rcpp CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp)

  - Pick a package and then look up the source at http://github.com/cran/packagename
- View an [annotated list](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cranusers.html) by Dirk here.